# Re-centering a map layer using manually input coordinates in GeoExt

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext

I am trying to create some code in GeoExt that will allow me to centre that map layer I am viewing to coordinates that have been submitted through a formPanel.

I thought that this would be fairly straightforward but it is proving to be troublesome.

Can you help?

So far I have created the the panel with 2 boxes to accept the eastings and northings but can't work out how to get the values that have been submitted to actually move the image.

The code I have cobbled together this far is:

```
formPanelCoord = new GeoExt.form.FormPanel({
    border: true,
    layout: 'anchor',
    bodyStyle:'padding: 20px',
        items: [{
        xtype: "textfield",
        width: 100,
        fieldLabel: "Easting",
        name: "search_lc",
        value: "",
        emptyText:'Easting',
        allowblank: false
    },

{
        xtype: "textfield",
        width: 100,
        fieldLabel: "Northing",
        name: "search_lc",
        value: "",
        emptyText:'Northing',
        allowblank: false
    }],



    listeners: {
       actioncomplete: function(form, action) {

        features = action.response.features;
        console.log(features.length)
     }



  }


});


formPanelCoord.addButton({
        text:"Go to Coord",
        handler:function() {
        console.log(formPanelCoord);
            //alert(formPanelCoord.items.items[0].getValue());
            //alert(formPanelCoord.items.items[1].getValue());
            formPanelCoord.items.items[0].getValue();
            formPanelCoord.items.items[1].getValue();
                       //function recentreMap (form) {
                       var easting = from.Easting.value;
                       var northing = form.Northing.value;
                       //var easting = formPanelCoord.items.items[0].value;
                       //var northing = formPanelCoord.items.items[1].value;
                       map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(easting,northing));
                       

formPanelCoord.addButton({
        text:"Go to Coord",
        handler:function() {
            this.search();
     },
     scope:formPanelCoord
});


            //this.search();
     },
     scope:formPanelCoord
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your points are latitude and longitude you can use the OpenLayers Map [`panTo`](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.panTo) function.

```js
//assuming map is the map object
//and x and y are in map projection
map.panTo(new OpenLayers.LonLat(x, y));
```

If your input points aren't in the map projection you'll have to [project](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Projection-js.html) them. If Eastings and Northings aren't in one of the default OpenLayers projections you'll have to include the [proj4js](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js/) library to build projection objects.

```js
//define a prjection, proj4 string from http://spatialreference.org
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:28355"] = "+proj=utm +zone=55 +south +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs";

in_projection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:28355");
map_projection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); //default OpenLayers map projection

zoom_point = new OpenLayers.LonLat(easting, northing);
zoom_point.transform(in_projection, map_projection); //in place transform
```